# TypeError: QgsMapLayerRegistry.addMapLayers(list-of-QgsMapLayer, bool addToLegend=True): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsVectorLayer

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis

I can't stop getting this error message when I try to run the following code in Qgis 2.14.10 :

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsDataSourceURI

uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setConnection("localhost", "5432", "name of my database", "my user name", "my password")
uri.setDataSource("database schema", "table name", "geom")
couche = "PM"
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), couche, "postgres")
if not layer.isValid:
    print ('Chargement de la couche: echec !')
else:
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers(layer)
```

> **TypeError: QgsMapLayerRegistry.addMapLayers(list-of-QgsMapLayer, bool addToLegend=True): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsVectorLayer**'

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add a single layer using a function designed for adding multiple layer**s**.

Either use

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

or put the single layer into a (single element) list

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```

Comment: Damn it I'm sorry ! I went through all the lines of my script again and again but I couldn't see that tricky "s" ! :)
Thanks !!!

Comment: Happens to everyone, at least two times.